# What is the expected behavior of Redis Sentinel if you accidentally write to a slave

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel

I'm trying to figure out what the expected behavior is in a Redis Sentinel setup (NOT Redis Cluster) if you accidentally issue a write command (such as `SET` or `BLPOP`) to a Redis slave. My instinct was that you would immediately receive back an error (though I don't know what the error code would be). We saw something strange today in our production environment that makes it seem like the actual behavior is that it blocks forever instead of immediately returning an error (in this case, `BLPOP` was the specific command we issued). I'm trying to figure out which rabbit hole to go down: The rabbit hole of our Redis configuration being wrong or the rabbit hole of our code being wrong. It would help if I knew what the expected behavior of a slave in Redis Sentinel is, but about two hours of Google has yielded nothing anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: See if this helps : https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/5229

Comment: No, that doesn't appear to be what's going on here. This isn't a replication problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my environment with Redis 4.0.1 and read-only slaves, an error is returned right away when setting values:

```
127.0.0.1:6380> get foo
"hi"
127.0.0.1:6380> set foo bar
(error) READONLY You can't write against a read only slave.
```

Slaves are read-only by default since Redis 2.6, you may find more info at https://redis.io/topics/replication